# zeros of a function in a simple closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, analytic-functions

i would really appreciate if you can help me with the following demonstration please:

Let $C$ be a closed simple contour such that $| f (z) | = cte$ ($f$ is analytic inside $C$ and is not an identical constant).  Show that $f$ has at least one zero inside $C$.

Comment: So the hypothesis is that f is analytic, constant on the border, and has a point inside the interior of the domain with a value different from the boarder ?

Comment: The hypotesis is that f is analytic, I don't know if constant on the edge, but it says that it is not an identical constant and I don't know if the other is also a hypothesis

Comment: Thanks I misread before. I did not notice that you had a modulus there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is analytic inside $C$ and continuous on $\operatorname{Int}C\cup C$ (here $\operatorname{Int}C$ denotes the interior of the simple closed curve $C$) we'll make use of the maximum principle which states that an analytic function attains its maximum values on the boundary of its domain given that such domain is bounded, which is the case here.

Assume $f$ has no zeros inside $C$ (i.e. in $\operatorname{Int}C$). Apply the maximum principle to $1/f$ to deduce that $f$ possesses a minimum value at some point $z_0\in C$. Then
$$
  M=|f(z_0)|\leq |f(z)|\leq M\quad\forall z\in\operatorname{Int}C
  ,
$$
where $M=|f|$ on $C$. We have now proved that $|f|=M$ on the whole of $\operatorname{Int}C\cup C$. What's left here is to prove that this condition implies that $f$ is constant, contrary to our hypothesis. I'll leave this to you: Consider the open mapping theorem for analytic functions.

Comment: What is the maximum of a complex function?

Comment: I take the maximum of a complex function $h$ to be the maximum of the real valued function $|h|$.

Comment: Whoops! Above $\partial C$ should be just $C$. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks I did not know this was a possible definition. Nice proof :)

Comment: No problem! :-D

Comment: Excuse me, what is it?

Comment: What of $ | f (z) | <= M $ is for C?

Comment: The minimum of $f$ must be attained on the boundary of its domain. In this case, the minimum is attained at some point $z_0\in C$. Then $|f(z)|\geq |f(z_0)|=M$. The same is true for its maximum. The maximum of $f$ is attained on the boundary, in this case, the maximum is attained at some point $z_1\in C$. Then $|f(z)|\leq |f(z_1)|=M$.

Comment: Thank you, very much!

Comment: ¡De nada! Es un placer ayudar.

Comment: Oh, disculpa, una última duda, M si es el límite, verdad?

Comment: $M$ es el valor de $|f|$ en $C$.